# Issues with PHP, PDO and pgpool

Tags: zend-framework, pdo

I have two computers with two Postgre databases. I am using PHP with PDO and working with pgpool.

Often times I receive this error

> ERROR:  pgpool detected difference of the number of inserted, updated or deleted tuples.

Or I get an error saying that the connection is out. Everything works fine without pgpool.

Is this is a known problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in different sequences of table

Comment: more details might help anyone else with same issue